# Where clause in a XML column

Tags: oracle, xml

I have the following XML column in my Oracle 11 G DB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l-analysis version="2.9">
   <vehicle>
      <odo-reading latest="true">
         <reading value="653463">653,463</reading>
         <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
         <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
      </odo-reading>
  <odo-reading latest="false">
     <reading value="391264">393,264</reading>
     <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
     <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
  </odo-reading>
   </vehicle>
</l-analysis>
```

I need to query the `reading value` but only `where odo-reading latest="true"`.

How can I do that in a `CLOB` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop table t1 purge;
create table t1 (id number, cxml clob);
insert into t1 values (1,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l-analysis version="2.9">
   <vehicle>
      <odo-reading latest="true">
         <reading value="653463">653,463</reading>
         <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
         <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
      </odo-reading>
  <odo-reading latest="false">
     <reading value="391264">393,264</reading>
     <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
     <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
  </odo-reading>
   </vehicle>
</l-analysis>');
commit;

select extractvalue(xmltype(cxml), 'l-analysis/vehicle/odo-reading[@latest="true"]/reading/@value') as value from t1;

VALUE     
----------
653463
```

Answer to the original question before it was edited:

```
drop table t1 purge;
create table t1 (id number, cxml clob);
insert into t1 values (1,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l-analysis version="2.9">
   <vehicle>
      <odo-reading latest="true">
         <reading value="653463">653,463</reading>
         <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
         <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
      </odo-reading>
   </vehicle>
</l-analysis>');
insert into t1 values (2,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<l-analysis version="2.9">
   <vehicle>
      <odo-reading latest="false">
         <reading value="653463">653,464</reading>
         <reading-date value="2018-12-04">4-Dec-2018</reading-date>
         <reading-unit code="K">Km</reading-unit>
      </odo-reading>
   </vehicle>
</l-analysis>');
commit;

select id, extractvalue(xmltype(cxml), 'l-analysis/vehicle/odo-reading/reading/@value') as value from t1
where extractvalue(xmltype(cxml), 'l-analysis/vehicle/odo-reading/@latest') = 'true';   

        ID VALUE     
---------- ----------
         1 653463
```

Comment: there are other `odo-reading` and I forgot to add it to my question. When running your query I get: `ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node` Please have a look at my updated question. I believe this happens because there isn't only one `odo-reading`.

Comment: @Manuela Added that version to the answer.

Comment: `EXTRACTVALUE` is deprecated.  Use `XMLTable()` instead.